Regex parsing "^[-\wÀ-ÿ\'\.\-\&\s]+$" - [x-y] range in reverse order
Older C# ASP.Net Web Form app with.Net Framework 4.6.2.
I have a regexp validator in an ascx user control:
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="REV_RecordId" runat="server" 
        ControlToValidate="uxRecordID" 
        ValidationGroup="TheValidationGroup" 
        Display="Dynamic" 
        ForeColor="Red"
        ErrorMessage="Please enter a valid ID" 
        SetFocusOnError="True" 
        ValidationExpression="^[-\wÀ-ÿ\'\.\-\&\s]+$" />

but when this control is loaded with
UserControl ctrl = (UserControl)LoadControl("path to user control");

I get the exception:

Inner Exception 1:
ArgumentException: parsing "^[-\wÃ€-Ã¿'.-&\s]+$" - [x-y] range in reverse order.

but any regex validator says "^[-\wÀ-ÿ'.-&\s]+$" is valid, the higher character component saying "matches a single character in the range between À (index 192) and ÿ (index 255) (case sensitive)".
So why would this fail with showing even stranger character interpretations?

"^[-\wÀ-ÿ'.-&\s]+$" is valid but  error throw different regex and "^[-\wÃ€-Ã¿'.-&\s]+$" is not valid. Are you sure there is no override to your regex exp. Or do you get this error from another validator

This looks like a character-encoding problem. Strings in .NET are UTF16-encoded. Your regex seems to assume the Windows-1252 code page. In the error message, Ã€ is the result of the (two-byte) UTF16-encoding of À being read as if it were Windows-1252 (one character per byte), and likewise ÿ => Ã¿. Without researching I can't tell you how to fix this for your case/environment but this should give you a starting point.

is there an  UTF16-encoded version of À and ÿ?

That is not the question you should be asking. The question you should be asking is "in which encoding have I saved the file containing my <asp:RegularExpressionValidator>, and in which encoding should I have saved it instead".

Thanks so much! The other pages that work are saved as Unicode (UTF-8 with signature) codepage 65001. This page that doesn't work is 'Western European (Windows) - Codepage 1252".  Please add this as an answer

@GSerg The correct file encoding by itself solved this issue. Thank you


is there an UTF16-encoded version of À and ÿ?

That is not the question you should be asking. The question you should be asking is "in which encoding have I saved the file containing my <asp:RegularExpressionValidator>, and in which encoding should I have saved it instead?"
Your regex is seeing a different expression than the one you have written in the file, which is because the file is not being read in the same encoding you saved it in.

You can use another notation for the Unicode characters:
ValidationExpression="^[\-\w\u00C0-\u00FF'.&\s]+$"

where À is represented as \u00C0 and ÿ as \u00FF.
Note your original regex contains redundant escapes and double declaration of a hyphen (at the start and then a \-), I kept the first one, and let's keep it escaped just in case you want to use the regex in the HTML pattern attribute later.
